# Importing the EasyDialogs module from stdlib_list

Tags: macos, python-3.x

I have Python 3.5.4 installed from MacPorts
After that I installed the Standard Library which contains the EasyDialogs module— `sudo pip install stdlib-list`

How do I install the EasyDialogs module? 
I tried— `from stdlib_list import EasyDialogs`